# How we can perform measurements on an X, Y or Z basis in cirq?

Tags: measurement, cirq

How we can perform measurements on an X, Y or Z basis in cirq? Is there any function where we can give the list of qubits and measurement basis as an argument and get the output?

Comment: I'd recommend reading through https://quantumai.google/cirq/build/pauli_observables - can you find what you need there?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://quantumai.google/reference/python/cirq/measure_paulistring_terms), you can execute measurement on any Pauli basis. Hope this helps!